# join two tables data in third table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables ,one sensor_info and other one is bays_info.here are the tables

```
id  Sensor_Name   stn_id    value  Station_id
1   Sensor1          0       4.4      1
2   Sensor2          0       2.1      1
3   Sensor3          0       3.2      1
4   Sensor4          1       4.5      1
```

Bays_info

```
gate_id     bay_name    bay_status    Station_id  

GATE1       B_gate1         1            1
GATE2       B_gate2        -999          1
GATE3       B_gate2         1            1
GATE4       B_gate2        -999          1
GATE5       B_gate2          1           1
```

Friends I need to show all "sensors value" for each gate, like below (here station id is common col)

```
gate_id     bay_name    bay_status    Station_id  Sensor1  Sensor2 sensor3 sensor4

GATE1       B_gate1         1            1         4.4       2.1    3.2      4.5
GATE2       B_gate2        -999          1         4.4       2.1    3.2      4.5
GATE3       B_gate2         1            1         4.4       2.1    3.2      4.5
GATE4       B_gate2        -999          1         4.4       2.1    3.2      4.5
GATE5       B_gate2          1           1         4.4       2.1    3.2      4.5
```

So I need to show value from sensor table for each station and also need to show sensor names as header.Please help me for MySQL query.

Comment: any relation between sensor_info and bays_info ? because i don't see any

Comment: @Punter015 station_id is common for both table

Comment: Consider handling issues of data sisplay at the application level (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array). It's more flexible and scalable than using a pivot query

Comment: @Punter015 station_id is common for both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   select gate_id  ,   bay_name ,   bay_status  ,  bays_info.Station_id,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'US.SEN1' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor1,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'US.SEN2' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor2,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'US.SEN3' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor3,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'DS.SEN1' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor4,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'DS.SEN2' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor5,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'DS.SEN3' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor6,
   max(case when Sensor_Name = 'MS.SEN1' then round(value,2) end) as Sensor7
   from bays_info
   inner join sensor_info 
   on sensor_info.Station_id = bays_info.Station_id
   group by gate_id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e69537/1)

Comment: bro I used your query ,query successfully run but sensors values are not coming blanks are there.all the sensor columns are empty ,other columns are having data.

Comment: for all sensors "NULL" value  is there

Comment: they shouldnt be null if you have exactly the values you gave, look if its right Sensor_Name or

Comment: stn_id is integer value that is int(10)

Comment: value is float and I just formatted the first table again.

Comment: same blank columns are coming there for sensors with your new query also bro

Comment: you see it works in my demo , it must be something wrong you done or you have other values. Please share your exact values.

Comment: your really insert values pls

Comment: I put all insert query above

Comment: ok i just updated my answer to fit your new results, please remove all those comments and put your new data in your own question , not here in comments , and if you still didnt make it to work i cant do more , its exactly from your values.